# How to remove duplicate in batch by calling another script / utility / program

Tags: batch, batch-file, duplicate, deduplication

i'm looking for a way to remove duplicate pictures via a batch file, but after asking on stack overflow, it turned out not to be doable without using external utility or software.

So i'm asking here, what software, utility or script can remove duplicate pictures (only keeping one of them) and can be called in a batch file?

Comment: Unless you wish to delete only duplicates, with identical filenames and size, it would be difficult to script.

Comment: you can try "comp" command. But it's not gonna work properly